# What type of t.test would you use for reaction time? Why does shapiro-wilk Test show reaction time data as not normally distributed?

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

```
Test %>% 
  filter(firstlanguage_cat %in% c("1", "2" )) %>% 
  t.test(firstlanguage_cat ~ Mean_RT_SIT1_Pre, data = ., 
         alternative = "two.sided")
```

> Error in t.test.formula(firstlanguage_cat ~ Mean_RT_SIT1_Pre, data = .,  :
> grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

##### How can I run the t.test?

I want to run an independent t.test for groups 1 and 2 in firstlanguage_cat for Mean Reaction Time without getting an error.

Comment: Reverse the formula variables, the factor with 2 levels is `firstlanguage_cat` not `Mean_RT_SIT1_Pre`.

Comment: What does the Shapiro-Wilk  test have to do with this question on a code error? That seems to be 1) a different question 2) a question on statistics, therefore off-topic here and better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I apologise. I put the 2 questions into one. I reversed the variables and the test was able to run.

Comment: I read some literature that says reaction time will never appear as normally distributed when a shapiro-wilk test is applied. I just wanted to confirm this is accurate.

Comment: For those 2 groups that I was testing the sample sizes are not equal. One is 54 observations and the other is 14. How should I proceed to get accurate p-value and go about the power calculation? Should use .05 or something else? Im an amateur at R so I would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: No need to apologize, questions are welcome. As for the Shapiro-Wilk test, if failure to detect normality is a characteristic of your subject matter then I probably am not qualified to answer.

Comment: Thar last question about power you should asl at Cross Validated, not here. And never in comments!

Comment: If sample sizes are different (and even worse, if variances are also different) an option is the [Wilcoxon rank sum test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html).

Comment: Appreciate it. Will post again on cross-validated